# jQuery AJAX can't fill select box in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have some code like this:

```
var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
mySelect.innerHTML = "<option>Loading...</option>";
$.get("ajaxPage.php", {"args":args}, function(r) {
    mySelect.innerHTML = r;
});
```

The ajax response is something like this:

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

And it works gracefully in Chrome, Aurora / Firefox, Opera and Safari (I've tested each one), but IE9 refuses to accept the response.

After looking at IE9's 'Inspect Element' window (I don't know exactly its name) I could see IE9 tries to render the response as a simple text node, such as:

```
Option 1Option 2
```

And why that happens is what is bugging me.

I'm sorry if that was already questioned here, I did a little searching and could see no answers that could help me.

TIA, André

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been an IE bug for as long as I can remember:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

I think that the JQuery equivalent has the bug fixed:

```
mySelect.innerHTML = r;
//change to
$(mySelect).html(r);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I wasn't thinking of the jQuery selector as an Object at first.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
$('#mySelect').html("<option>Loading...</option>");
```

It seems like IE is not evaluating your HTML, jQuery should take care of that issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

The only good practice for any browser, and the only working with Internet Explorer is using DOM, not just html'ed string. Something like this:

Code:

```
<script>
$('select#my_select')
    .append($( document.createElement('option') ).val('opt1').html('Option 1'))
    .append($( document.createElement('option') ).val('opt2').html('Option 2'));
</script>
```

**Before**:

```
<select id="my_select"></select>
```

**After**:

```
<select id="my_select">
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2">Option 2</option>
<select>
```